# Checkout previous success version (revision) in teamcity

Tags: integration, teamcity, ca

Oure teamcity server (6.5) configured to checkout sources from SVN. For some build proceess cases I need checkout previous successfully builded version(revision). Can teamcity do this? And if can, how to configure checkout?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for TeamCity [Snapshot Dependencies](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Dependent+Build#DependentBuild-SnapshotDependency), with the "Only use successful builds from suitable ones" option.

You'd end up with two build configurations:

1. Performs initial builds on commit to SVN
2. Has a snapshot dependency on #1, so when this build runs (either automatically - via a [trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+Build+Triggers) - or manually), it grabs the same sources as the last successful build of #1.

Both of the build configurations would use the same VCS root.

Comment: Doesn't the Snapshot Dependency option "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one" handle the scenario you described?  I just tried running a "step 2" build in our environment and it used an existing successful "step 1" build - no rebuild.

Comment: touche - you are correct. My issue was something else. I've removed my comment.